# How to read function keys?

Tags: gwt

I have a widget with a FocusPanel, and I read KeyPress events. Is it possible to define which function key pressed?
I tried to use event.getUnicodeCharCode(), but I can scan only Enter (code-13) an Ctrl-Enter (10) function keys.

1. So is there any way to fire function when Esc-key pressed?
2. What other function keys and how I can scan?

Comment: If you mean the function keys on laptop, no. The function key combination is built in the board.

Comment: I mean not only F1-F12, I mean Esc, Backspace, Cursor arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nativeKeyCode` instead.

Here is the [list of keyCodes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

```
    FocusPanel  panel = new FocusPanel();
    panel.addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
             if(event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() ==KeyFromLIst){
                 //DO something
               }

        }
    });
```

In Order to get Rid-off browser incompatibility prefer `keyup handler`.

Comment: Thanks, in IE I can scan Esc(27) now, but no effects in Chrome.